# Calculate summary with AngularJs on selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning the AngularJs and I've created a dynamic list with `ng-repeat`, but now I cannot find the solution for the next step...

I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="list" ng-controller="ListController">

        <div class="row" ng-repeat="prod in prodList">
            <div class="prod-name cell">
                <input type="checkbox" id="prod-{{ prod.id }}" data-ng-model="orders.prods.prod[prod.id]" value="{{ prod.id }}" data-cb="" /><label for="prod-{{ prod.id }}">{{ prod.name }}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="prod-size cell">
                <label for="prodColor-@{{ prod.id }}">
                    <select id="prodColor-{{ prod.id }}" data-ng-model="orders.prods.color[prod.id]" data-ng-options="color.id as color.name for color in prod.colors">
                        <option value="">Select one</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="prod-price cell">
                {{ prod.price }}
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="sum">
            {{ sum }}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", [], function () {
});

app.controller('ListController', function ($scope) {
    init();

    function init () {
        $scope.prodList = [{"id":"1","name":"window","colors":[{"id":"9","name":"white"},{"id":"11","name":"black"}],"price":"100"},{"id":"2","name":"door","colors":[{"id":"22","name":"blue"},{"id":"23","name":"red"}],"price":"356"},{"id":"3","name":"table","colors":[{"id":"37","name":"white"},{"id":"51","name":"black"}],"price":"505"}];
        $scope.orders = {};
        $scope.orders.prods = {};
        $scope.orders.prods.prod = {};
        $scope.orders.prods.color = {};
        $scope.sum = 0;
    }
});
```

**Working demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/HDrzR/

**Question**

How can I calculate the summary of selected product's price into the `$scope.sum`?

*Edited:*

So if you select the "window" and the "table" from the list, the sum should contains 606. But if you unselect the "table" then the sum should be 100.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you rephrase/clarify your question? I'm not sure what you mean by "summary of selected product's price".

Comment: Each product has a price. I need the selected products' price in $scope.sum. So if you select a checkbox from the list then that price should added to sum (and if uncheck it, remove it from sum of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either `$watch` over `$scope.orders.prod` and re-calculate the sum or (if performance is not a major concern and the list of objects is not huge) you could use a `sum()` function and reference it in the view:

```
Total: {{sum()}}

$scope.sum = function () {
    return $scope.prodList.filter(function (prod) {
        return $scope.orders.prods.prod[prod.id];
    }).reduce(function (subtotal, selectedProd) {
        return subtotal + parseInt(selectedProd.price);
    }, 0);
};

/* If the above looks complicated, it is the equivalent of: */
$scope.sum = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.prodList.length, i++) {
        var prod = $scope.prodList[i];
        if ($scope.orders.prods.prod[prod.id]) {
            sum += parseInt(prod.price);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

If you decide to go down the watching path, this is how the code should look like:

```
Total: {{watchedSum}}

$scope.sum = ...;   // same as above
$scope.$watchCollection('orders.prods.prod', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
        $scope.watchedSum = $scope.sum();
    }
});
```

<sub>**UPDATE:**

"Stole" Quad's `$watchCollection` as this is more "cheap" than `$watch(..., true)`.

As long as `$scope.order.prods.prod` contains only rimitive values (i.e. no objects), `$watchCollection` is enough to detect the changes.</sub>

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/a22HS/)** illustrating both approaches.

Comment: +1 I liked this one, it seems the right way to do it.

Comment: I know @SystemExpert is sharing an alternate solution but why a watch would be necessary here? I do not see it

Comment: @Dalorzo: As mentioned in the answer, the `$watch` alternative has its merits (in terms of performance). The 1st approach will run `sum()` with every digest loop (even if the `prod` list hasn't changed). The approach using `$watch` will run `sum()` only if `prod` has changed. Usually this is not a concern as the impact is unnoticable, but if sum is computationally expensive (e.g. too many items or too large prices or whatever), then saving those extra computation miht have noticable impact on app responsiveness (with 0 cost).

Comment: Sum occurs during UI Action trigger on change MVVM suggests ngChage: <input type="checkbox"
       ng-model=""
       ng-change="addItUp()">

Comment: NgChange can easily replace watch listener, ngChange will trigger less than the second one

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. One thing to keepin mind though is that initialization should be manually taken care of (in a real-world example, `prodList` wouldn't be hard-coded in the controller, but rather fetched from a backend, so initialization should be manual (probably with a `$watch` over `$scope.prodList`). But, that said, `ngChange` should be the most performant solution.

Answer (score 1):

here is an updated fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/HRQ9u/

what I did is add a `$scope.$watch` on the orders:

```
         $scope.$watch('orders', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var findProdById = function (products, id) {
                for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    if (parseInt(products[i].id, 10) === parseInt(id, 10)) {
                        return products[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            };
            var orders = newValue;

            var usedProducts = newValue.prods.prod;
            var sum = 0;
            for ( var prop in usedProducts ){
               var prodList = $scope.prodList;
               var id = prop;
               if ( usedProducts[id] ){
                   var product = findProdById(prodList, id);
                   if ( product !== null ){
                       sum += parseInt(product.price, 10);
                   }
               }
            }
            $scope.sum = sum;
        }, true);
```

Edit:

With that said, you can probably simplify your model a lot. And I mean A LOT.

Also, I have used only regular js as opposed to lodash or underscore.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, that it summarise everything which is in prodList. But what I need is only the selected ones from the list.

Comment: @baba I read some where in SO  that it is always better to share the code as part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/HDrzR/3/)

You can $scope.$watchCollection your scope to calcuate new sum. I chaged your prodList prices to number instead of string, and used underscore.js for easier looping in your objects/arrays.

```
 $scope.$watchCollection("orders.prods.prod",function(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0;i<$scope.prodList.length;i++){
        if($scope.orders.prods.prod[$scope.prodList[i].id]){
            sum += $scope.prodList[i].price;
        }
    }
    $scope.sum = sum; 
});
```

[watchCollection docs are here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

edit: changed with regular js answer

Comment: $watch and underscore is adding 2 layers for simple sum.

Comment: underscore can simply be replaced with regular js, used here just for convenience

Comment: It would have been a better answer if you did it regular js instead

Comment: Well, here it is. removed underscorejs dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Register an **ng-click** with **checkbox** and pass **$event** & **prod.id** references to a custom function that will be called on checkbox **click** event.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="prod-{{ prod.id }}" data-ng-model="orders.prods.prod[prod.id]" value="{{ prod.price }}" ng-click="calcSum($event, prod.id)" data-cb="" />
```

Within **controller** define custom function as:

```
$scope.calcSum = function($event, id) {
         var checkbox = $event.target;

        if (checkbox.checked  ) {
            $scope.sum += parseInt(checkbox.value);   
         } else {
            $scope.sum -= parseInt(checkbox.value);    
         }  
}
```

Change the Checkbox **value** attribute to store **{{ prod.price }}** instead of {{ prod.id }}, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

From my POV it looks more appropriate to use is **`ngChange`** from the `input[checkbox]` itself. Like:

```
ng-change="addMe(prod.price);"
```

We need a way to differentiate checked from not checked and in order to change less your app we will use the existence of the object by it doing this way:

```
ng-change="addMe(orders.prods.prod[prod.id],prod.price);"
ng-true-value="{{ prod.id }}" 
ng-false-value=""
```

The full **HTML** will look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="prod-{{ prod.id }}" data-ng-model="orders.prods.prod[prod.id]" ng-change="addMe(orders.prods.prod[prod.id],prod.price);" ng-true-value="{{ prod.id }}" ng-false-value="" />
```

From your **Controller** all you need is to add or substract when necessary:

```
$scope.addMe=function(checked,val){
  val = 1*val
  if (!checked){ $scope.sum = $scope.sum-val;}
  else { $scope.sum =  $scope.sum +val; }
}
```

Here is the [**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HDrzR/4/)